# Extract directory from wget's stdout

Tags: shell, command-line, shell-script, tar, wget

I am trying to `wget` a tarball from github.com and, without creating a temporary file, extract a subdirectory from it:

```
wget -qO- https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel/tarball/develop | tar xzf - django
```

It gives me an error saying:

```
tar: django: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Apparently I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the django directory itself is a subdirectory of the resulting gzip content, you'll need to use the `--strip-components=1` option of GNU tar.  Assuming you're using GNU tar.  Then you need to tell tar that you're looking for a subdirectory called `django`.

```
wget -qO- https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel/tarball/develop | tar --strip-components=1 -zxf - \*/django
```

FWIW, I also had to use the `--no-check-certificate` option of `wget`.

Comment: thanks. that worked. I had to add --wildcards option as well.